# How can I detect and block delete events in an EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview, android-edittext

I have a Fragment which has an EditText. I would like to override the behavior of the delete key in the EditText, but only for certain words. The logic of whether to override the delete event is held within the Fragment, and the EditText does not have access to the Fragment.

Example:
A user is typing: "Hello, my name is Adam and I am 23." The cursor is set immediately following "Adam", and the user taps the delete key. "Adam" is one of my keywords that should not be deleted, so I want to instead move the cursor to just before the word, and cancel the delete event.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- OnKeyListener. This only works for hardware keyboards, and I need a solution for both virtual and hardware keyboards.
- OnEditorActionListener. This does not trigger on a delete press.
- Override the onCreateInputConnection method, with one of my creation which overrides the sendKeyEvent method. I can't do this because its creation must be inside the EditText (needs super access), but the logic of what words should not be deleted resides in the Fragment (which the EditText does not have access to). I cannot pass in the logic from the Fragment to the EditText because it is constantly changing.
- TextWatcher. This successfully triggers before, while, and after text has been deleted, but cannot stop the deletion.

Any ideas that I have not yet tried would be much appreciated!